# How to write only the 5th value from a list into a csv

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am reading several csv sheet with the `opencsv` libary. I am storing the "read" csv file in `hugeList = reader.readAll();` Now I only want to only write the 5th value of this huge csv sheet columnwise in another sheet.

At the moment I am standing at:

```
        //reading all entries in a huge list
        //-740 as it would take to much time to run it in "dev mode"
        for (int j = 0; j < (fileList.size() - 740); j++) { 
            String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\" + fileList.get(j);
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), ';');
            hugeList = reader.readAll();            

            List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
//          for(int m = 0; m < hugeList.size(); m++) {
//              String[] value = hugeList.get(m);
                data.add(hugeList.get(5));
//          }

            writer.writeAll(data);

        }
```

However I have no idea how to write them into another column and just take the 5th value?

I really appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE 1**

**Goal:** I have saved all values from one sheet at the time in hugeList. Now I want to 
write only the 5th column into a new sheet.

**Problem:** The logic behind this goal.

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
//reading all entries in a huge list
for (int j = 0; j < (fileList.size() - 740); j++) { 
    String csvFile = "C:\\" + fileList.get(j);
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), ';');
    hugeList = reader.readAll();            

    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    List<String> tmp= new ArrayList<String>();
     for(int m = 0; m < hugeList.size(); m++) {
              String[] values = hugeList.get(m);
              tmp.add(values[0]);       
       }
     data.add(tmp.toArray(new String[0]));


    writer.writeAll(data);

}
```

As you can see I get my data still vertically... Why?

Comment: could you please elaborate the requirement and the problem

Comment: Try to explain your code in [SSCCE format](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Why are you iterating over the inner array?  Isn't `hugeList` just an array of `String` arrays or something?  The inner array should be the csv lines, broken into fields, so you should be able to simply do `writer.write(hugeList[i][5])`.  I think you are over-complicating things by trying to make a `List<String[]>`.

Comment: As I understand the question: The OP is getting the list of values from the csv sheet from `fileList` in `hugeList`. Then ,I think, he wants to give out only the 5th value of each sheet in a column. Is thi correct user2051347?

Comment: @user1000 yes, that is basically what I meant!

Comment: @user2051347 look at my update i thinks it can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing you are already on the right way.

You have 2 possibilities.

```
1. data.add(hugeList.get(4));

2. for(int m = 0; m < hugeList.size(); m++) {
         if(m==4){
              String[] values = hugeList.get(m);
              data.add(values);
          break;
         }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Goal: I have saved all values from one sheet at the time in hugeList. Now I want to write only the 5th column into a new sheet. Problem: The logic behind this goal.

[image]
**My Approach for a result in rows**

```
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        List<String> tmp= new ArrayList<String>();
         for(int m = 0; m < hugeList.size(); m++) {
                  String[] values = hugeList.get(m);
                  tmp.add(values[4]);       
           }
         data.add(tmp.toArray(new String[0]));
        }
```

**My Approach for a result in Column**

```
 for (int j = 0; j < fileList.size(); j++) {
    String csvFile = readPath + fileList.get(j);
    System.out.println("Read:  " + csvFile);
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), ';');
    hugeList = reader.readAll();

    String[] data = new String[1];
    for (int m = 0; m < hugeList.size(); m++) {
        String[] values = hugeList.get(m);
        data[0] = values[0];
        writer.writeNext(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! I am still getting the data verticaly not horizontally... I would appreciate it if you could have a look at my update!

Comment: @user2051347 May be you can send me your code if you don't have nothing against it? and a little example with excel about what you want exactly to achieve? festus@tamakloe.de

Comment: @user2051347. Ok i get the email with 2 attchments. I'll work on it and send it back to you today

Comment: @user2051347 what is the meaning of this line "  for (int j = 0; j < (fileList.size() - 740); j++) { "

Comment: I have over 1000 files therefore I just limit the read files by substracting -740 from the `fileList.size()`. In fact this is just for `development mode`.

Comment: @user2051347 i send you a mail

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44730/discussion-between-user2051347-and-festus-tamakloe)